# Migrating MS Project 2010 Addin to MS Project 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2010, ms-office, add-in, ms-project

I want to know below details regarding migration of MS Project 2010 Addin to MS Project 2013.

Can I migrate MS project 2010 VSTO style addin to 2013 using Visual Studio 2010?
Can I migrate MS project 2010 COM addin developed using IDSExtensibility2 to MS Project 2013 using Visual Studio 2010?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't any problems with making cross-version add-ins for MS Office applications and MS Project is one of them.

What you should do is to add a reference to the newest version of MS Office Interops and keep in mind that some of the COM calls could be unavailable in the older versions. But in general they keep the most of the core calls compatible across the versions.

I believe starting from .NET 4 you can embed COM Interop Types into your assembly so you don't even need to keep them as an installation dependency for your project.